# gregorian calendar returns previous day date when toGregorianCalendar().getTime() is called

Tags: java

Following is piece of code:

```
customerDetailsType.getDateOfBirth().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
```

When I inspect the value of `customer.getDateOfBirth()` in eclipse debug mode, it shows me current date.

When I inspect the value of `customerDetailsType.getDateOfBirth().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()`, it shows me previous day date.

The return value of `customer.getDateOfBirth()` is of type: **XMLGregorianCalendar**.
I am calling a webservice and passing Date object as dateOfBirth to server.
The above code is on server.

Definition of dateOfBirth is like :

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")

protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;
```

Comment: Sounds like it could very well be a time zone issue. Please provide sample input data, and details of how you're observing the values at different stages. Note that a `Date` object represents an instant in time, which may fall on different local dates depending on the local time zone.

Comment: Please see my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a timezone problem. `GregorianCalendar` has sub-second granularity. Debug your code to see what the time (hours, minutes, seconds) and timezone components of your `getDateOfBirth()` method is. It might be converting to local time or UTC which is shifting the date. Since your application probably doesn't care about the hours, minutes, seconds of someone's date of birth (and isn't displaying it), the displayed date may just be a day earlier.

Comment: value for getDateOfBirth: 2013-09-23+01:00
value for customerDetailsType.getDateOfBirth().toGregorianCalendar().getTime(): Sun Sep 22 23:00:00 UTC 2013

these values are when i debugged the code and when I inspect teh values.

Dont know much about timeZone issue, Could you please help

Comment: @Manglesh: Those two values represent the same point in time, just from the perspective of different time zones. That was my point in the comment - a `Date` represents an *instant* in time. It has no concept of a time zone in itself, or even a calendar system. As such, it doesn't imply a particular date, because that would depend on the time zone and calendar system.

Comment: agreed, but then how can this be resolved. as if I enter date of birth for customer, it should be same as passed from webservice request. because in this case, client passes 23 while in the database (serverside) its 22nd. any idea.

Comment: The database and the client are actually referring to the same instant in time. The way to get around this is to ensure that the database and client are both working in the same time zone. If all times in your client are coming out as UTC+01:00, then your database should assume UTC+01:00. If your client allows for multiple timezones, then make your database speak UTC and convert all client times to UTC before persisting them. Consistency is your friend.

Comment: I am running both client and server (webservice) on the same local host. so they both are in same time zone but I still see this issue. I understand about this timezone issue however dont understand why it would be if client and server are on my local system

Comment: The local system might not be automatically converting dates to and from its native timezone. Because many applications use UTC (in particular, UNIX times), there's likely an implicit conversion somewhere that you're not seeing. Good luck!